# Creating a fixed length navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I create a navbar like below which has `260px` on left side and `260px` on right side with center `100%` width.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="brand" href="#">Project X</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Menu 2
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/10/

How can I create a navbar like below which has `260px` on left side and `260px` on right side with center `100%` width.

Comment: Do you want "ProjectX" and "Result" text at the two corners (260px width) or they should be included in center width ???

Comment: THey sould be included in the two corners with 260px width

Comment: And what about Home & Menu Links ??? Should they be at the center ?

Comment: Logo and Home in left and a simple text on right... center space is 100% width.

Comment: Remove "pull-right" From "<ul class="nav pull-right">" and reply. http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/16/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/15/

Comment: Do you need the same ???

Comment: @Ankur140290: yes as I looks in the screenshot with bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2):

Remove `"pull-right"` From `<ul class="nav pull-right">`

New Code: [jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/16](http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/16)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="brand" href="#">Project X</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Menu 2
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gvw7j/14/)

```
.nav{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
.left{
    width:260px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
.center{
    width:calc(100% - 520px);
    width:-moz-calc(100% - 520px);
    width:-webkit-calc(100% - 520px);
    height:30px;
    background:gray;
    float:left;
}
.right{
    width:260px;
    height:30px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
}


<div class="nav">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```